# I'm Trying to create a recipe book program in python but recipe won't print

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
print("What would you like to make?")

recipes=["Smash Burgers","Pizza","Fried Chicken"]

for recipe in recipes:
    print (recipe)

Choice= input(recipes)
if Choice==recipes [0]:
    print ("Potato Buns Ingredients,415 g bread flour,45 g potato flakes ,1 Tbsp instant yeast ,1 Tbsp kosher salt,2 Tbsp sugar,170 g water (75-80°F) ,110 g whole milk (75-80°F),2 eggs, room temperature  ,4 Tbsp unsalted butter, cubed + room temperature,Egg wash (see recipe below),Egg Wash Ingredients: ,1 egg ,1 egg yolk ,Pinch of salt ,Smash Burgers Ingredients: ,16 oz chuck, ground ,8 oz brisket, ground ,8 oz boneless short rib, ground ,As needed neutral oil ,To taste kosher salt, To taste freshly ground black pepper,American cheese,Potato buns, toasted,Butter lettuce ,Beefsteak tomato, sliced,White onion, thinly sliced,Bread and Butter pickles, sliced ,Special sauce (see recipe below),Special Sauce Ingredients:,½ cup mayo ,½ cup ketchup,⅓ cup mustard, ¼ onion, grated 1 garlic clove, grated ½ tsp hot paprika ,1 Tbsp relish")
    
    if Choice==recipes [1]:
        print("FOR THE DOUGH:270g or 1 1/8c water (86F/30C),30g or 2 Tbsp olive oil ,5g or 1 3/4 tsp instant yeast,35g 8 1/3 tsp sugar,430g or 3 1/2c ap flour (11.7% protein or similar),12g or 2 1/8 tsp salt. PIZZA SAUCE: 150g or 2/3c tomato paste,150g or 2/3c water, 1g or 1/8 tsp salt ,10g or 2 1/3 tsp sugar,10g or 2 1/4 tsp olive oil ,1/4 tsp dried basil ,1/4 tsp dried oregano,1g or 1/2 tsp black pepper,1g or 1/3 tsp garlic powder,1g or 1/2 tsp onion powder. TO BUILD AND BAKE THE PIZZA:200g or 2c full fat aged mozzarella, grated ,90g or less than 1c aged provolone, grated,finely ground cornmeal (for dusting),flour (for dusting),pinch of salt") 

else:
        print=input("Select a valid recipe. Or Would you like to make one?")
```

I created a list the contains all the foods and used an if statement to create a condition that would print out the recipe. I had done it once for the 0 index but the next index wouldn't print and would only print what was on the else statement

I've tried to change the formatting of the code (Sorry if its hard to read) but nothing seemed to help.

Comment: Check your indentation.  Your `recipes[1]` case is nested inside your `recipes[0]` case, so you'll only see recipe 1 if it's the same as recipe 0.  You probably want all your recipes to be part of an `if...elif...elif...else` chain (all at the same indentation level).

Comment: `print=input(...)` I don't think that that's what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, the recipe must be equal to the first recipe before judging the second recipe. Perhaps you can change the code to the following

```py
print("What would you like to make?")

recipes = ["Smash Burgers", "Pizza", "Fried Chicken"]

for recipe in recipes :
    print(recipe)

Choice = input(recipes)
if Choice == recipes[0] :
    print(
        "Potato Buns Ingredients,415 g bread flour,45 g potato flakes ,1 Tbsp instant yeast ,1 Tbsp kosher salt,2 Tbsp sugar,170 g water (75-80°F) ,110 g whole milk (75-80°F),2 eggs, room temperature  ,4 Tbsp unsalted butter, cubed + room temperature,Egg wash (see recipe below),Egg Wash Ingredients: ,1 egg ,1 egg yolk ,Pinch of salt ,Smash Burgers Ingredients: ,16 oz chuck, ground ,8 oz brisket, ground ,8 oz boneless short rib, ground ,As needed neutral oil ,To taste kosher salt, To taste freshly ground black pepper,American cheese,Potato buns, toasted,Butter lettuce ,Beefsteak tomato, sliced,White onion, thinly sliced,Bread and Butter pickles, sliced ,Special sauce (see recipe below),Special Sauce Ingredients:,½ cup mayo ,½ cup ketchup,⅓ cup mustard, ¼ onion, grated 1 garlic clove, grated ½ tsp hot paprika ,1 Tbsp relish")

elif Choice == recipes[1] :
        print(
            "FOR THE DOUGH:270g or 1 1/8c water (86F/30C),30g or 2 Tbsp olive oil ,5g or 1 3/4 tsp instant yeast,35g 8 1/3 tsp sugar,430g or 3 1/2c ap flour (11.7% protein or similar),12g or 2 1/8 tsp salt. PIZZA SAUCE: 150g or 2/3c tomato paste,150g or 2/3c water, 1g or 1/8 tsp salt ,10g or 2 1/3 tsp sugar,10g or 2 1/4 tsp olive oil ,1/4 tsp dried basil ,1/4 tsp dried oregano,1g or 1/2 tsp black pepper,1g or 1/3 tsp garlic powder,1g or 1/2 tsp onion powder. TO BUILD AND BAKE THE PIZZA:200g or 2c full fat aged mozzarella, grated ,90g or less than 1c aged provolone, grated,finely ground cornmeal (for dusting),flour (for dusting),pinch of salt")

else :
    print = input("Select a valid recipe. Or Would you like to make one?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match/case statement since it's more readable and easier to maintain in your situation:

```
print("What would you like to make?")

recipes = ["Smash Burgers", "Pizza", "Fried Chicken"]

for recipe in recipes:
    print(recipe)

Choice = input(recipes)
match (Choice):
    case "Smash Burgers":
        print("recipe1")
    case "Pizza":
        print("recipe2")
    case "Fried Chicken":
        print("recipe3")
    case _:
        print(
            "Select a valid recipe. Or Would you like to make one?")
```

Keep in mind that match/case got introduced in Python 3.10 so it won't work if you have an older version of python installed.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of your indentation. The condition `if Choice==recipes [1]` is inside the condition `if Choice==recipes [0]`. You should always remember that indentation in python is very important. Modify your code like this:

```
print("What would you like to make?")

recipes=["Smash Burgers","Pizza","Fried Chicken"]

for recipe in recipes:
    print (recipe)

Choice= input(recipes)
if Choice==recipes [0]:
    print ("Potato Buns Ingredients,415 g bread flour,45 g potato flakes ,1 Tbsp instant yeast ,1 Tbsp kosher salt,2 Tbsp sugar,170 g water (75-80°F) ,110 g whole milk (75-80°F),2 eggs, room temperature  ,4 Tbsp unsalted butter, cubed + room temperature,Egg wash (see recipe below),Egg Wash Ingredients: ,1 egg ,1 egg yolk ,Pinch of salt ,Smash Burgers Ingredients: ,16 oz chuck, ground ,8 oz brisket, ground ,8 oz boneless short rib, ground ,As needed neutral oil ,To taste kosher salt, To taste freshly ground black pepper,American cheese,Potato buns, toasted,Butter lettuce ,Beefsteak tomato, sliced,White onion, thinly sliced,Bread and Butter pickles, sliced ,Special sauce (see recipe below),Special Sauce Ingredients:,½ cup mayo ,½ cup ketchup,⅓ cup mustard, ¼ onion, grated 1 garlic clove, grated ½ tsp hot paprika ,1 Tbsp relish")
    
elif Choice==recipes [1]:
    print("FOR THE DOUGH:270g or 1 1/8c water (86F/30C),30g or 2 Tbsp olive oil ,5g or 1 3/4 tsp instant yeast,35g 8 1/3 tsp sugar,430g or 3 1/2c ap flour (11.7% protein or similar),12g or 2 1/8 tsp salt. PIZZA SAUCE: 150g or 2/3c tomato paste,150g or 2/3c water, 1g or 1/8 tsp salt ,10g or 2 1/3 tsp sugar,10g or 2 1/4 tsp olive oil ,1/4 tsp dried basil ,1/4 tsp dried oregano,1g or 1/2 tsp black pepper,1g or 1/3 tsp garlic powder,1g or 1/2 tsp onion powder. TO BUILD AND BAKE THE PIZZA:200g or 2c full fat aged mozzarella, grated ,90g or less than 1c aged provolone, grated,finely ground cornmeal (for dusting),flour (for dusting),pinch of salt") 

else:
    print=input("Select a valid recipe. Or Would you like to make one?")
```

In this updated version, the indentation is removed from the `if Choice==recipes [1]` condition and changed the conditional statement to `elif Choice==recipes [1]`